# React ReCharts - Tooltip does not work on Safari (but works fine on Firefox)

Tags: reactjs, linechart, recharts

I've created a simple ReCharts - Line Chart with one data element (Date & Value). Chart is working fine but the tooltip only works when I run this on Firefox. The chart is unresponsive (or static) on Safari (v14.1.1) on a Mac.

```
       <div className="card">
        <LineChart width={950} height={300} data={this.props.inputdata} margin={{ top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 5, left: 20 }}>
          <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Total_Returns_Index" stroke="#8884d8" />
          <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
          <XAxis dataKey="Date" />
          <YAxis domain={[500, 2000]} />
          <Tooltip />
          <Legend />
        </LineChart>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think I understand what the issue might be. I am parsing the data using Papa Parse and then using it to Setstate. There appears to be some issue with this SetState which is causing it to keep control of the browser (infinite loop of some sort?) which is likely resulting in this.

Comment: Well the Papaparse was parsing it too fast (even before the render is complete), added a tiny amount of delay and it is all working fine now.